# RSpec expect is failing while comparing equal strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I tried to update this test but it is failing to compare identical strings, even though I copied and pasted the "got" output back into the test case. Why is this RSpec test failing?

```
 Failure/Error: expect(first_item_cost).to eq("12 x $499 = $5,988")

   expected: "12 x $499 = $5,988"
        got: "12 x $499 = $5,988"

   (compared using ==)
```

Code:

```
first_item_cost = find('.cart-item-cost', match: :first).text
expect(first_item_cost).to eq("12 x $499 = $5,988")
```

RSpec 3.9

Comment: I tried updating to `RSpec 3.10` but it didn't help.

Comment: They might look the same, but might be actually different. Check `first_item_cost.encoding` and then compare both strings `<str>.bytes`. My guess there might be some special character there.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the encoding and bytes and discovered:

```
puts "Encoding: " + first_item_cost.encoding.to_s
puts "Bytes: " + first_item_cost.bytes.to_s
```

Output:

```
Encoding: UTF-8
Bytes: [49, 50, 32, 195, 151, 32, 36, 52, 57, 57, 32, 61, 32, 36, 53, 44, 57, 56, 56]
```

The 'x' has too many bytes! I looked in the template and sure enough it used `&times;`. When I copied and pasted from the console, it must have lost the original character (or RSpec translated it before output). I changed the spec and template to `x`.